# BootStrap DataTables not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

All I'm trying to do (for right now) is duplicate the table in the example for DataTables:
http://www.datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2

I have it on my server here:
http://myestoretemplates.com/tts/test.php

And it is showing up with double rows and the pagination is not working. I'm figuring I'm doing something wrong, but the problem is - I have all the scripts I'm supposed to have, right? All the js files in the working example are included in my example.

I'd appreciate any help - thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're initializing the table twice in your javascript.

The first is done at the bottom of your DT_bootstrap.js, the second time is in the  tag after your call to DT_bootstrap.js.

Remove one of the extra calls and it should render properly.